# Unable to process this regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have the following "greekSymbols.txt"

```
Α α alpha
Β β beta
Γ γ gamma
Δ δ delta
Ε ε epsilon
Ζ ζ zeta
Η η eta
Θ θ theta
Ι ι iota
Κ κ kappa
Λ λ lambda
Μ μ mu  
Ν ν nu
Ξ ξ xi
Ο ο omicron
Π π pi
Ρ ρ rho
Σ σ sigma
Τ τ tau
Υ υ upsilon
Φ φ phi
Χ χ chi
Ψ ψ psi
Ω ω omega
```

I was trying to convert this into a Anki plain text file with a tab as the delimeter. I was converting each row into two cards where the front is the symbol (in uppercase or lowercase) and the back is the name. I have the following.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(.)\s+(.)\s+(.+)", re.UNICODE)

input = open("./greekSymbols.txt", "r")

output = open("./greekSymbolsFormated.txt", "w+")

line = input.readline()

while line:

    string = line.rstrip()

    m = pattern.match(string)

    if m:
        output.write(m.group(1) + "\t" + m.group(3) + "\n")
        output.write(m.group(2) + "\t" + m.group(3) + "\n")
    else:
        print("I was unable to process line '" + string + "' [" +  str(m) + "]")

    line = input.readline()

input.close();
output.close();
```

Unfortunately, I am currently getting the "I was unable to process ..." message for every line, with the value of str(m) being None. What am I doing wrong?

```
> localhost:Anki stephen$ python ./convertGreekSymbols.py 
I was unable to process line 'Α α   alpha' [None]
I was unable to process line 'Β β   beta' [None]
...
```

Comment: I updated with the regular expression changes suggested by the answers, but I am still getting no matches. I also removed the newline, in case that was causing something to happen.

Comment: Do you know the encoding of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need a regex for this:

```
with (open("./greekSymbols.txt") as infile, 
      open("./greekSymbolsFormated.txt", "w+") as outfile):
    for line in infile:
        up, low, name = line.split()
        outfile.write("{0}\t{1}".format(up,name))
        outfile.write("{0}\t{1}".format(low,name))
```

If you want to stick to regex, try the following regex instead of yours (which should work IMO, but which perhaps isn't explicit enough):

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.+)", re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: Thank you, part of the whole process here is learning RE, though I appreciate the help.

Comment: @StephenCagle: I have added a regex suggestion. I would have expected your regex to work - possibly the problem is related to some characters being represented by multi-byte sequences in UTF-8 (which I assume you're using), and that aren't matched by a single `.`, although I would have expected it to work on a character-based level, not byte-based. But since I'm not in a Unix environment, I can't test it here.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that it's the whitespace parsing that's wrong. Shouldn't it be `(.)\s(.)\s(.+)`, rather than `\t`? You don't seem to have tabs in your input.

Comment: I believe I do have tabs, it seems that pasting it to HTML deletes them?

Answer (score 2):

You're having a \t where there is no tab, should be \s:

```
>>> matcher = re.compile(r"(.)\s(.)\t(.+)", re.UNICODE) 
>>> phi = "Φ φ phi" 
>>> matcher.match(phi)
>>> matcher = re.compile(r"(.)\s(.)\s+(.+)", re.UNICODE)
>>> matcher.match(phi)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1018d8290>
>>>
```

Comment: Can't argue with your logic, but I am still getting the error?

Comment: Can you try with \s+ (I updated above). Might be that your tab is multiple whitespace chars. If that does not work, can you paste a line to pastebin or something equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that finally got things working. It appears that the original file my have been utf-8, and this was causing problems. Here is the working solution that allowed me to create a /t seperated import file for Anki.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import re
import codecs

pattern = re.compile(r"(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.+)", re.UNICODE)

input = codecs.open("./greekSymbols.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")

output = codecs.open("./greekSymbolsFormated.txt", "w+", encoding="utf-8")

line = input.readline()

while line:

    string = line.rstrip()

    m = pattern.match(string)

    if m:
        output.write(unicode(m.group(1) + "\t" + m.group(3) + "\n"))
        output.write(unicode(m.group(2) + "\t" + m.group(3) + "\n"))
    else:
        print("I was unable to process line '" + string + "' [" +  str(m) + "]")

    line = input.readline()

input.close();
output.close();
```